# no msgs shown while following actionlib tutorial

Tags: actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following [this](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionServer%28ExecuteCallbackMethod%29) tutorial on action lib:`Writing a Simple Action Server using the Execute Callback` But after i build the package and than run the fibonacci_server node i'm not getting any ROS_INFO as shown in the tutorial like this:
`[ INFO] 1250790662.410962000: Started node [/fibonacci], pid [29267], bound on [aqy], xmlrpc port [39746], tcpros port [49573], logging to [~/ros/ros/log/fibonacci_29267.log], using [real] time`
When i checked the rqt_graph I'm getting:
[image: image description]
When i run `rostopic list -v`, i'm getting:

```
Published topics:
 * /fibonacci/feedback [actionlib_tutorials/FibonacciActionFeedback] 1 publisher
 * /fibonacci/status [actionlib_msgs/GoalStatusArray] 1 publisher
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log] 1 publisher
 * /fibonacci/result [actionlib_tutorials/FibonacciActionResult] 1 publisher
 * /rosout_agg [rosgraph_msgs/Log] 1 publisher

Subscribed topics:
 * /fibonacci/goal [actionlib_tutorials/FibonacciActionGoal] 1 subscriber
 * /fibonacci/cancel [actionlib_msgs/GoalID] 1 subscriber
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log] 1 subscriber
```

My CmakeLists.txt file is exactly as instructed but after i run the command line: `rosrun actionlib_tutorials fibonacci_sver` what i get is nothing.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251553/no-msgs-shown-while-following-actionlib-tutorial/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2017-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Everything is all right here. To get the image shown in the tutorial (which was taken from `rxgraph`, an older alternative to `rqt_graph`:

1. change visualization in the drop down to `Nodes/Topics (all)`
2. uncheck the `Actions` check box, as well as the `Dead sinks` and `Leaf topics`

But I must say I am unsure why the `ROS_INFO` output does not appear. Maybe this has been removed from rosrun?

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2017-01-09**:
o thanks, hurray.